# Android Ble Scanning callback not getting triggered continuously

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

**Requirement** : I have a requirement where I have to scan for near by ble devices at continuous basis.If an attribute of ble device changes,the device emits the ble signal which my app captures.But these things should be done at continuous mode.

**Problem** : In some of the android device (such as **one plus 1,samsung tab 3,Moto droid turbo**) the scancall back wil get triggered only once and is not scanning at continuous basis as per my requirement.I have tested some of other devices (such as **one plus 3,samsung tab 4,moto g2**)where in the scan callback gets triggered every single time.Is there any solution where in even other devices to get scan callback everytime...I have checked with all the scan modes,but yet the same problem persists...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately some of the Android devices do not return Scan results continuously as this is not mandatory according to BLE protocol (I witnessed it on LG devices).  The workaround is to initiate Start and stop scan.  See [This useful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29731725/5144446)

Comment: Yes I have checked on the above mentioned approach.But do we need to reinitialize all the variables such as bluetooth adapter,scancallback and then start and stop scan or just start and stop the scan??

Comment: Just stop and start scan as far as I know.